# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0 (slack-webhook)

Tags: java, ssl, slack, java-7, sslexception

I am developing a batch application.

I need to send message using slack webhook api

'local' -> slack webhook (send message) -> success
(succeed local)

but,

'dev' -> slack webhook (send message) -> fail
(fail dev)

The reason is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0

The 'dev' server builds the batch via a Linux shell file on Jenkins.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:524)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:506)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
    
2022-11-21 18:51:08 [ERROR] javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
```

my environment :

- local, dev : java.version 1.7.0_80, java.class.version 51.0

what i tried

- -Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
- -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
- SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
- X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager()
- jdk8 build
- System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
- System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to an SSL enabled server ? Check what is running on the port you are testing.